# Is it possible to measure the object using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, computer-vision

Is there a way we can measure the length, width and the depth of an object in the picture using deep learning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without some kind of reference object. I also don’t see a reason to use deep learning for such a task.
Sure - you could create a dataset with all kinds of objects and their typical dimensions. But the results for inference would probably be pretty bad and the effort to create the dataset ridiculously huge.